# Use a condition while creating a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to create a table with a condition

```
create table TOTO
(
    Id int not null, 
    zip  as (if(zip > '00999' and zip < '96000') then zip) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

All I get is an error message.

Do you know how to do that with the "zip" in type char ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using sql server management studio

Comment: I want the zip code between 01000 and 95999

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: Do you want to stop other values to be stored, then use a check constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [CHECK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) constraint instead

```
CREATE TABLE TOTO
(
    Id int NOT NULL, 
    zip char,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CHECK (zip > '00999' AND zip < '96000')
);
```

Comment: zip = '00ZZZ' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done either using a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints) or using a `BEFORE INSERT` or [`INSTEAD OF`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx) trigger

An example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ChkZip
ON TOTO
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   IF (inserted.zip > '00999' and inserted.zip < '96000')
   BEGIN
         INSERT INTO TOTO (id,zip) VALUES (insered.id, inserted.zip)

   END 
   ELSE    
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('The entered zip code doesn't match criteria.' ,10,1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END    
END
```

Comment: This should work and it is always good to be aware of all the possibilities you have well but is it really worth it? What is the added value of such a complex solution *in this precise case* except the custom error message?

Comment: @C.Champagne, right and that's what said in answer ... it's an alternative. constraint answer already posted and so alternative answer. do remember that trigger is kind a generic solution ... example MySQL have no `CHECK` .. just a note but yes if it can be done using  constraint then that's what should be opted first

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new  [CHECK constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints) so that your field is guaranteed to comply with this constraint each time it is set or modified (insert or update).

Here is an example adapted to SQL server (as you seem to be using that dbms) where the constraint is named so you can identify it more easily (better for maintainability)

```
create table TOTO
(
     Id int not null, 
     zip  char ,
     PRIMARY KEY (Id),
     CONSTRAINT CHK_zip CHECK(zip > '00999' and zip < '96000') 
);
```

Note that you could formulate it using patterns as in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE TOTO
        (
            Id  INT NOT NULL,
            zip VARCHAR2(10),
            PRIMARY KEY (Id),
            CONSTRAINT CHK_zip CHECK (zip > to_number('00999') AND zip < to_number('96000'))
        );`

You could use check constraint - the above script is based on Oracle Sql function